# Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined when trying to aply a filter based on a user's input

Tags: arrays, angular, filter

Im trying to aplly tis simple filter ased on a query of a list that with each input the list will narrow the possibilities

HTML:

```
 <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Search for users</mat-label>
                <input #query type="text" matInput placeholder="search" (keyup)="filter(query.value)">
            </mat-form-field>
            <div *ngIf="filteredUsers">
```

And the function:

```
filter(query){
    this.filteredUsers= query?
    this.users.filter(user=>user.username.includes(query)):
    this.users;
  }


                <ul *ngFor="let u of filteredUsers">
                    <li>
                        {{u.username}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

The error I get as I input a character id that filter is undefined, but since both arrays fileterdUsers and Users are populated, I can't understand why this error is beig thrown...Any ideas?

EDIT: the ngOninit:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
     this.dataService.getUsers()
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(users=>{

      this.filteredUsers=this.users=users;
      console.log(users, this.filteredUsers) -> i get the data
    }) 
  }
```

Edit 2 :

[image: These are the logs of the on intit]

EDIT

```
filter(query){
    console.log(this.users)
    this.filteredUsers= query?
    this.users.filter(user=>user.username.includes(query)):
    this.users;
    console.log(this.users)
  }
```

Like this I don't see any logs...

EDIT 3: snapshot

Ok, maybe I have an idea of whats going on. The first elements of my ngFor are empty as you can see in the picture. Is this the reason for Angular's complaint? (your last fix didn't solve the issue as well)

[image]

Comment: This you try a console.log(this.users) right before filtering?

Comment: yes, I get data from both filtering and users array

Comment: what is console.log(this.users) printing exactly?

Comment: i will ad a snapshot

Comment: the query also logs, but then the program stops with the error so I cant have the log o fthis.users at the end of the filter function

Comment: add it as the first line in the filter function, and I need to see the data expended for atleast one user

Comment: dont follow, shall I add a console.log(this.users) in the firts line of the query function?

Comment: There is no query function, just a filter(query)

Comment: Try `this.users.filter(user => user.username && user.username.includes(query))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If console.log doesnt log your array, it means its empty at the time filter(query) is being called. And I just noticed the way you are assigning the array isnt really what you want since arrays work by reference.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
     this.dataService.getUsers()
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(users=>{
      this.filteredUsers=users;
      this.users=users; //just to be sure
      console.log(users, this.filteredUsers) -> i get the data
    }) 
  }
```

filter returns an array so I guess you want to assign that to the filteredUser. I removed the code that made no sense.

```
filter(query){
    console.log(this.users)
    this.filteredUsers = query ? this.users.filter(user=> user.username && user.username.includes(query)): this.users
    console.log(this.filteredUsers)
  }
```

Comment: Im very sorry for this late reply, but the error remains; and as you could see in my post, the filter method has a ternary operator that is asking if is there a query (a char). Ive seen this working; as you type the table gets narrowed until you match the one you look for

Comment: @Mellville I didnt even see the ternary, this is not how you should format it! I just added back the ternary.

Comment: ok, I'm going to try your ngOninit code and your ternary

Comment: that was it, the first elemnts of the array were empty, thats why this filter was giving me an arror

Comment: @Mellville so this is the answer?

Comment: yes, but if you want the credit, and write a better text, be my guest, because you actually pointed me in the right direction

Comment: @Mellville well you used the code I provided, and the thing about having empty elements wasnt provided in the question so I cant include that in the answer but I can modify the filter to allow empty element without crashing.

Comment: yes, true, I havent provided this first empty elements wich cause all the issue. The original code works, of course, I just had to delete the empy elements; cleaning them was the solution, was nothing about code nor logic. Im being fair with you but i have a responsablility as well, I can't mark your answer as correct, unless you provide a better text/ explanation. Anyways, I aprecciate your envolvment

Comment: Did you try the edited filter without removing the empty objects? The explanation depends on what an empty object means to you, is it: {} or { username: ''}. My guess is {} but I just want to make sure first.

Comment: Honnestly, I used my original code because I've seen it working on other projects; the issue was, again, having empty array's elements, and angular was searching for them based on a query, that's why the app broke. I can inlude your name in my answer is that ok?

Comment: Yes and no, the answer is not to delete the empty element but to use a better condition to make sure it doesn't break if it happens

Comment: ok...I see your point, so edit your post,give it the full explanation and I will mark it correctly

Comment: Is my code working right now because I changed the filter condition?

Comment: your filter condition actualy strenghs the script, bu if i haven't deleted the empty stuff your code would not work...so what should we do? now you got me lost

Comment: Yes it would, the filter doesn't care about the contain as long as there is an object. What was breaking was, I think, user.username didnt exist so includes was throwing an error

Comment: well, the best solution is to leve this as is. Others can see our ideas and our undecisions :) What do you think?

Comment: Thats on you to decide, but I would add the code to remove the empty objects in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whith the help and envolvment of @ukn I found the solution: the first elements of the array - seen on pic - , in this case users, were empty, so the solution was deleting those elements. The filter function is now working properly, giving me the names as I input a single char. The list gets updated trying to match the chars I input.